# How do I pass arguments to a Java instrumentation agent?

Tags: java, arguments, instrumentation, javaagents

How do I pass arguments to a `java.lang.instrument` instrumentation agent? [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) simply states:

> `-javaagent:`*jarpath[=options]*

What *options* can I select?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To pass arguments to a Java agent, append them after the equals sign:

```
java -javaagent:/path/to/agent.jar=argumentstring -cp jar-under-test.jar Foo.Main
```

The arguments are treated as a single string and passed to your `premain` method. You are responsible for any further processing of the arguments, e.g. splitting on commas or separating `key=value` pairs.

```
public static void premain(String agentArgument,Instrumentation instrumentation){
  // args passed in 'agentArgument'
}
```

**Note:** if you don't pass any arguments to your agent (i.e. omitting the equals sign), the `agentArgument` argument will be **null**, rather than an empty string.

Comment: how can I pass a non-null `instrumentation` argument?

Comment: instrumentation is provided by the JVM, that is not something that is user-controlled.